# Django auth with redis

Tags: django, session, authentication, redis

I try to plug in my django aplication into microservice architecture.

Authentication is made by component written in spring boot. It stores session in redis in following format:

```
"spring:session:sessions:71f06a1d-b169-4bb9-a4c8-013bb82742ee"
```

Is it possible to configure some existing django lib (configure namespace) to use build in auth system? I would like to avoid write down whole thing from scratch.

Any help will be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed the problem - that kind of functionality provides custom authentication 
 http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#example .

Comment: Can you share code how do you do it ?